# Changing the font of the text in a table cell

Tags: c#, fonts

This might be a very trivial question but I just can't find a solution by myself.

so I have a table cell as below and I want to change the text in it to courier font

```
    TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();
    tableCell.text = "1234"
```

I've tried this:

```
    tableCell.CssClass = "font: Courier";
```

I've looked into the font properties of both text and TableCell. Text does not have any properties and TableCell's font does not allow me to set its value.

[Source 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.text(v=vs.110).aspx): [Source 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell(v=vs.110).aspx)

Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CssClass on server elements doesn't work like that, you are giving it the class name to pick up in CSS

```
tableCell.CssClass = "CourierText";


//css
    .CourierText { font: Courier; }
```

Or you could add individual rules, but class is much better practice

```
tableCell.Attributes["style"] = "font: Courier";

tableCell.Attributes.Add("style", "font: Courier");
```